# Script to run command at exactly X seconds past each minute

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

I'd like to run a bash script, for use on a Raspberry Pi, that says "if the seconds of the current time is exactly 00 or 30, then do X".

I've googled and found some suggestions to use cron, but I think there'd be a small delay at the start which I want to avoid.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like the delay of cron, which is mostly for background stuff, you could loop in the foreground:

```
while true; do
    d=$(date +%S)
    if [ $d -eq 0 -o $d -eq 30 ]; then
        # command here
        date +%S.%N
        # replace the above command with whatever you want
        sleep 5
    else
        sleep 0.001
    fi
done
```

The Linux `date` command can check the current system clock quite quickly. I've used this loop to print the nanosecond timer with `data` to demonstrate the low latency. That is, on my system, I get:

```
30.001057483
00.003022980
30.003011572
```

and so on.

Comment: `sleep 0.001` is like busywait. Why don't you determine the exact time to sleep and sleep exactly once between the executions of the target command?

Comment: Because sleep is not precise

Comment: Thank you @Leo-Izen, that's exactly what I wanted and it works well!